# Python - Get the type returns of strings that represent built-in functions

Tags: python

Say I have some text of some Python code,

```
"''.join(something)"
```

I may not know what something is but if the text is parsed, we'd see join, which is a built-in python function. There must be a way to know that it returns a str. Ideally, I'd like a function to just do

```
get_type("''.join(something)")  # Returns: 'str', because join make a 'str'
```

or another situation,

```
"['asdfom', whatever].append('ttt')"
```

something like eval() to get object types can't be used because key 'whatever' is unknown, but we know that append returns None so the solution should know that the return type is None

Here's another more complex situation, where the type is unknown but its method is likely* (*within a reasonable guess) to be a certain type

```
"some_string_variable.split('\n')"
```

some_string_variable could be any name and it may not even be defined in the same file, but split() is a method known to the python str type so, if some get_type function were to try and guess the return type, it would use what it knows, split() and match it with what str.split() returns, which is a list. I'm fine with this circumstance to not have 100% accuracy but the two situations I listed above should have working solutions.

Right now, I'm using pydoc.locate() which works pretty well in a lot of cases, even for user-defined types, but it returns None in all of the cases above. Does anyone know of a way to make what I'm looking for?

Comment: You need to rely on the documentation. So, try `help("".join)` for example

Comment: "Read the documentation" is the only meaningful answer.  Functions don't have to return homogeneous type in Python.

Comment: In Python we code for objects' interfaces not the types of objects. This is a fundamental design concept. You should always code for an object interface and care less about the type of object you'll be receiving or processing. This is done by avoiding type testing. Python is so dynamic, unlike Java or C where functions return a certain data types. However, you need type testing sometimes, I see `help` very helpful for that purpose you mentioned.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original examples.

The code being used is not typed values but all strings. So an object interface in this case isn't knowable